# Have object detect if completely inside other object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection, collision

Hello I'm making a game for my CS class using JavaScript. I know how to ale objects collide with each other in the canvas but I m trying to get an object to detect if it's completely inside another object

```
If (object1.xcoord > object2.xcoord 
     && object1.xcoord + object1.width < object2.xcoord + object2.width 
     && object1.ycoord + object1.height < object2.ycoord +object2.height) {
  alert("hi")
}
```

Note I only need those three sides it doesn't matter to me if object 1 is within top side of object 2

Also is it possible to only use comparisons like < or > and not anything else

Comment: What shape is it, and are both of them the same shape?

Comment: @Viliami both are rectangles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//both height and width need to be smaller than the containing objects height
//and width.
if(obect1.width < object2.width && object1.height < object2.height){
    //check if right side x of object1 is less than right side x of object2
    //and check if bottom y of object1 y is less than bottom y of object2
    //and check if left x of object1 is greater than left side x of object2
    //and check if top y of object1 is greater than top y of object2
    if(object1.x+object1.width < object2.x+object2.width 
    && object1.y+object1.height < object2.y + object2.height
    && object1.x > object2.x && object1.y > object2.y){
        return True;
    }
}
return False;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your code only checks to make sure the bottom side and the right side. The code still returns true even if object 1 is to the left of object 2