# JavaScript: Detect if DOM element overlaping, inside or ouside with DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a small game in JavaScript. I've created a small example [js fiddle demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/r7vuaw8h/3/). There are three situations as listed bellow:

- A: Outside of target object.
- B: Overlaping with target object's border.
- C: Inside of target object.

According to [Have object detect if completely inside other object JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945374/have-object-detect-if-completely-inside-other-object-javascript), I've known how to detect if the object inside of target (Situation C). How about situation A and B?

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="target"></div>
    <div class="obj">A</div>
    <div style="top:15%; left:50%;" class="obj">B</div>
    <div style="top:25%; left:35%;" class="obj">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use [`Element#getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to obtain the absolute coordinates of the DOM elements being classified for overlap, containment, etc.

This function returns to `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` coordiates of the corresponding DOM element which you can use to determine containment of an `element` with respect to a `container`.

You could implement a function like `findContainment()` shown below, where the containment of `element` is classified against a `container` element:

```js
function findContainment(element, container) {

  /*
  Obtain the bounding rectangle for each element 
  */
  const brE = element.getBoundingClientRect()
  const brC = container.getBoundingClientRect()

  /* 
  If the boundaries of container pass through the boundaries of
  element then classifiy this as an overlap 
  */
  if (
    /* Does container left or right edge pass through element? */
    (brE.left < brC.left && brE.right > brC.left) ||
    (brE.left < brC.right && brE.right > brC.right) ||
    /* Does container top or bottom edge pass through element? */
    (brE.top < brC.top && brE.bottom > brC.top) ||
    (brE.top < brC.bottom && brE.bottom > brC.bottom)) {

    return "overlap";
  }

  /* 
  If boundaries of element fully contained inside bounday of
  container, classify this as containment of element in container
  */
  if (
    brE.left >= brC.left &&
    brE.top >= brC.top &&
    brE.bottom <= brC.bottom &&
    brE.right <= brC.right
  ) {
    return "contained"
  }

  /* 
  Otherwise, the element is fully outside the container 
  */
  return "outside"

}

const main = document.querySelector(".main")
console.log("A", findContainment(document.querySelector(".a"), main))
console.log("B", findContainment(document.querySelector(".b"), main))
console.log("C", findContainment(document.querySelector(".c"), main))
console.log("D", findContainment(document.querySelector(".d"), main))
console.log("E", findContainment(document.querySelector(".e"), main))
```

```css
.main {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.obj {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div style="top:105%; left:25%;" class="obj a">A</div>
  <div style="top:15%; left:-5%;" class="obj b">B</div>
  <div style="top:20%; left:40%;" class="obj c">C</div>
  <div style="top:20%; left:110%;" class="obj d">D</div>
  <div style="top:90%; left:95%;" class="obj e">E</div>
</div>
```

Here's a [working fiddle as well](https://jsfiddle.net/k8z9facd/) - hope that helps!

Comment: The fiddle link you provided is the same as mine. Could you please update it?

Comment: @peggy sorry about that, just updated - does that help?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want.  Thank you.